# dns.gethostbyname()

Tags: c#, .net, dns, ipv4

i've been searching online about the Dns gethostbyname change to gethostentry, and modify the code accordingly, but why still not display the normal ipv4 address?
here my code:

```
string GetHostIP()
    {      
        String myHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();

        // Find host by name
        System.Net.IPHostEntry myiphost = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(myHostName);

        String ipstring = "";
        foreach(System.Net.IPAddress myipadd in myiphost.AddressList)
        {
            ipstring = myipadd.ToString();
            return ipstring;
        }
        return ipstring;
    }
```

Comment: it show something like this: fe80::5efe:192.168.0.19%10 ,but i got it solved now, thanks to Hans Passant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are trying to make you stop assuming the IP address is a dotted-decimal IPv4 address.  They just can't get IPv6 off the ground and that's necessary.  Completely out of free addresses as of a couple of months ago.

You can get the IPv4 address, you'll have to fish it out explicitly:

```
        foreach (System.Net.IPAddress myipadd in myiphost.AddressList) {
            if (myipadd.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork) {
                return myipadd.ToString();

            }
        }
        throw new WhatTheHeckException();
```